# How to find the name of a killed process?

Tags: process

I am using linux processes running through a scheduler. The scheduler is also a linux process, and it calls the processes in the right order. In order to start every thing, I run a script, which calls all the processes. Let s say I have 10 components, I am expecting 10 linux processes. However, Linux seems to start more than that, it seems some components are using more than one process, and these additional processes are not tracked. I recently had the case that one of this untracked process is crashing during the init, and the console only gives me the PID, but not the process name. Because of that, debugging is harder, because I don t really know which node has crashed. Of course, I can list the active nodes to deduce which one is missing, but it doesn t scale well.

```
/home/catkin_ws/application_sw/middleware_sol/dol_runtime.sh: line 233: 25518 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${LIDAR_START_COMMANDS[${ix1}]}
```

Is there an easy way to find the name of a crashed process? It is very easy to find the name of an active process, but the name of a dead one? The problem here is that the process only lives few ms and directly dies.

Thanks

Comment: You mention Linux many times, but never what OS & release you are using.  This isn't SE *Unix & Linux*, so why are you asking here?

Comment: Hi, I thought this kind of command would not be specific to a distribution. For instance, ps -aux gives the running process.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04